# Accessing response data from Express using Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I want to access an authenticated user's data from my front-end using Angular.

This is the response from Express on Node.js.

#### routes/dashboard.js

```
exports.build = function (req, res) {
    res.render('dashboard', {
        uid: req.user._id
    });
};
```

I grab the `uid` through the `ng-init` directive, currently.

#### views/dashboard.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    block styles
  body(ng-app='App', ng-controller='MainCntrl', ng-init='setUId(#{JSON.stringify(uid)})')
    // some content
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.0.1/q.js')
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/ng-app.js')
```

However, I would like to avoid doing this.

#### public/javascripts/ng-app.js

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.factory('User', function () {
    return {
        // Promise for retrieving JSON User data
        getProperties : function (id) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            $.getJSON('/api/user/' + id
            , function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).fail(function () {
                deferred.reject(true);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

app.controller('MainCntrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'User', function ($scope, $http, User) {
    $scope.uid, $scope.user;
    $scope.setUId = function (id) {
        $scope.uid = id;
    };
    $scope.initUser = function () {
        User.getProperties($scope.uid).then(function (user) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.user = user;
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
}]);
```

I would like to pass this `uid` data to Angular without having to use the `ng-init` directive. Is there a way to access the response data, something along the lines of:

```
console.log(res.body.uid);
```

Retrieving the `uid` param from the response would remove the need for the `ng-init` directive. How would I go about retrieving it?

Comment: Have you used Angular before? Not so sure, as it's a really open ended question. If you haven't then I would recommend doing the tutorial over here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial - essentially you would want a service that in injected in your controller; the service fetches the data and the controller uses it.

Comment: I've used it before! Also, I updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more, and perhaps elegant solution would be to have the User ID in the URL and map a route to accept an `id`.

Then your controller can look more like this

```
app.controller('MainCntrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'User','$stateParams', function ($scope, $http, User, $stateParams) {       
    // NOTE: I do not know which route engine you're using, though you would inject
    // its parameters provider in here, to get access to the url parameter (userId) of the route
    // so for this example, i have assumed ng-router hence the injection of $stateParams
    // the getProperties() method here is assuming ng-routet

    User.getProperties($stateParams.id).then(function (user) {        
        $scope.user = user;
       }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);

     });      
}]);
```

Comment: By including the User ID in the URL, do you mean a query parameter like `http://some-url.com/?uid=*********`?

Comment: It can do, though would more likely (if setup correctly) be some - url.com/userid or some-url.com/users/userid

Comment: If I have more than one user, then wouldn't there be confusion as to whose `uid` data would be a response from a URL like `some-url.com/users/userid`?

Comment: No.thats the point. The user with id would only see data for that Id.  You would pass that along to your service that gets the data.

Comment: Just to clarify.  You would replace "userid", in the url in your comment with the users actual id. .